# Delay script loading

Tags: javascript

So if I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="offsite file I am referencing"></script>
```

and I simply want to delay the execution of calling that file using settimeout, how would I go about that?

Very strange in that I would have no problem using settimeout on a simple function, but I am kind of stumped in this seemingly more simple situation.

My thought would be I could just make a function that calls that file after x amount of time, but calling the file in the function seems to be escaping me.

Comment: I'm just curious; what are you trying to achieve with this? Is it purely experimental?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

you are almost there.

in your settimeout callback function do the following:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "http://whatever.com/the/script.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Thanks, I basically had this figured out and I couldn't make it back here fast enough to update!!

Comment: I stumbled onto this anwser before finding the answer I really wanted using jQuery and promises here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803215/how-to-include-multiple-js-files-using-jquery-getscript-method)

Answer (score 18):

The simplest way would be to let the script file load normally and just call a main function in it with `setTimeout()` like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="offsite file I am referencing"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(executeMainFunction, 5000);    // function in offsite js file
</script>
```

If you cannot do that for some reason, then you can delay the loading of the external script file like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         
    var newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    newScript.src = 'http://www.somedomain.com/somescript.js';
    headID.appendChild(newScript);
}, 5000);
```

Here's a reference article on dynamic loading of script files (and other types of resources): http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Howto_Dynamically_Insert_Javascript_And_CSS.

Comment: How to run a function/work after inserting and waiting for 5 seconds?

Answer (score 6):

You can use DOM manipulation to create a new script tag at runtime. Adding it into the document will load the external JS file just as if you had written it into the HTML in the first place.

```
var loadScript = function(sourceSrc){
    var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
    scriptTag.src = scriptSrc;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can delay the script from loading, until the page finishes loading, using the [HTML script defer attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp):

```html
<script src="offsite file I am referencing" defer></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

If the purpose of this exercise is to delay the loading of external resources to simulate potential real life scenarios (e.g. when loading 3rd party widgets, etc), then I'd go down a very different route.

The following are two different delay proxy implementations that can be used to simulate and test unexpected network conditions:

- http://www.deelay.me/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-connect-delay

They both work by using a prefix like `/delay/5000/` to specify the delay simulation period.

Answer (score 2):

#### Mozilla Developer Network explains various approaches:

[MDN Async Script Techniques](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/Async_scripts)

```
<script async src="file.js"></script>
```

or

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "file.js";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

or if your JavaScript is in a String:

```
var blob = new Blob([codeString]);
var script = document.createElement('script');
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
script.onload = script.onerror = function() { URL.revokeObjectURL(url); };
script.src = url;
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

There is also good information when *async is not async* as well as how to get around those cases.

Answer (score 0):

I have created for ReactJS and its worked for me.

**1. File: widget.js with promise:**

```
const delayTime = 20000; // loading 20sec delay.

const loadJS = async () => {
    return await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.async = true;
        script.src = 'https://yoururl.com/js/widget.js';
        script.onload = resolve;
        script.onerror = () => {
            reject('Cannot load js')
            document.head.removeChild(script);
        }
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    }) }

function initLoadJS() {
    loadJS()
    .then(()=> console.log('testing'))
    .catch((error)=>console.error(error)) }

function delayLoadingJS() {
    setTimeout((event)=>initLoadJS(event), delayTime); 
} 
export default delayLoadingJS;
```

**2. Calling *delayLoadingJS()* function on the page:**

When page loading completed then after 20 sec later *initLoadJS()* method will trigger and it attach the 3rd party javascript file(https://yoururl.com/js/widget.js) on page.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.page !== prevState.page) {

      delayLoadingJS();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a NextJS cript, the code below will work fine:

```html
<script  id="sample_id">
    setTimeout(function(){
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "https://link_to_load";
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
     },
     4000);
</script>
```