# Import multiple files using jQuery.getScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to include multiple js files using jQuery $.getScript() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803215/how-to-include-multiple-js-files-using-jquery-getscript-method)

I need to import multiple files within a .js file, I'm looking at the getScript jQuery method : 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ but this just loads one file wheras I want to load 3.

Is there an alternative method for achieving this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803215/how-to-include-multiple-js-files-using-jquery-getscript-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the `getScript()` method 3 times or as many times as the number of script files you want to import.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want something like this

```
var files = array('filename1', 'filename2');

for (var file in files) {
    $.getScript(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this like this, but you will have to call each of the scripts, and the order they load, in this example in file 3 we use the callback for executing a function.

```
$.get("js/file1.js")
.pipe($.get("js/file2.js"))
.pipe($.get("js/file3.js", {}, function()
{
    runFunction();
});
```

Comment: **Deprecation Notice**
  $.pipe method is deprecated since jQuery 1.8. You can read more about it [over here](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/).

Apart from that, this is a good mechanism.