# jQuery widget loading required scripts

Tags: jquery

I'm building a large jQuery widget and I have some scripts I depend on to run this widget. Of course I could just include them in my html page but that not so hot. I need to load them from my widget.

I know about $.getScript but unfortunately it seems like it will run the code after the end } before running what is in it. It also does not cache the scripts which will slow are site down.

I've tried the LazyLoad plugin, same deal as $.getScript(), it will run the code after the function before what's in it.

What I'd like to do is in the _create function I could just call this._dependencies() and load all the required scripts I need and then continue in _create.

Here's some code:

```
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    $.widget("test", {
        create: function () {
            this._dependencies();
            $..setLocale(this.locale);
        },
        _dependencies: functio() {
            LazyLoad.js(['jquery.i18n.js', 'test.i18n.js'], function () {});
        }
    });
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Comment: We'd need to see code, it appears as though you might be using `$.getScript` in a synchronous manner rather than asynchronous. Also, `$.getScript` by default will allow the browser to do caching.

Comment: ;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {
    $.widget( "test" , {
  _create: function () {
            this._dependencies();
            
            $._.setLocale(this.locale);
  },
  _dependencies: functio() {
   LazyLoad.js([
                    'jquery.i18n.js', 
                    'test.i18n.js'
                ], function() {
            });
  }
 });

})( jQuery, window, document );

Here's a sample. I have an error at setLocale. sorry don't know how to format the text properly in a comment.

Comment: Comment's aren't really meant for that much code, it should be included in your question.

Comment: `$..setLocale` will cause a syntax error in javascript, did you mean `$.setLocale`?

Comment: no that's a plugin, it's $.[underscore].setLocale()

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803215/how-to-include-multiple-js-files-using-jquery-getscript-method but how would I include my whole plugin with this code. I've tried only putting the plugin call in there but doesn't work.