# jQuery getScript() not resolving

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred, getscript

I am using jQuery's `getScript()` to load separate javascript files. The files seem to load fine (I know this as when I put an incorrect URL, it throws an error - no error with the correct URL).

However, the `done()`function does not seem to work. The console does not log 'done', nor do any of the functions get called.

```
(function($) {
    $.when(
        $.getScript( templateUrl + "/assets/js/variables.js" ),
        $.getScript( templateUrl + "/assets/js/functions.js" ),
        $.getScript( templateUrl + "/assets/js/events.js" ),
        $.Deferred(function( deferred ){
            $( deferred.resolve );
        })
    ).done(function(){

        console.log("done");

        swapBackgroundImgs();
        singleLarge();
        bindFlexorder();
        bindSvgeezy();
        bindPlaceholder();
        preloadImages();

    });
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `done` callback is never triggered because you've explicitly created a `Deferred` and never resolved it. `$.when` waits for *all* of the promises to be resolved.

The code you have in your `$.Deferred`:

```
$( deferred.resolve );
```

...will schedule the `Deferred`'s `resolve` function as a `ready` callback, but the function will get called with the wrong `this` (`document` rather than the `Deferred` object; more: [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)), which probably makes it throw an error `ready` buries.

Simply remove that `$.Deferred` entirely, or if your goal is to wait for `ready`, make sure `this` gets set correctly when calling `resolve`:

```
$.Deferred(deferred) {
    $(function() {
        deferred.resolve();
    });
})
```

or:

```
$.Deferred(deferred) {
    $($.proxy(deferred.resolve, deferred));
})
```

or, but note the comment:

```
$.Deferred(deferred) {
    // Deprecated in jQuery 1.8
    $(document).on("ready", deferred, "resolve");
})
```

Comment: What you've said makes sense. I found out about multiple getScript() from [this stack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11803418/997596) which is why my code was like that. I've removed the `$.Deferred` yet still nothing in `done()` is getting called. Would it have anything to do with the jQuery function wrapper?

Comment: @tommyf: It wouldn't be because of the wrapper in the code you've shown, but if you're also using that wrapper in the scripts you load, then yes: The functions in those scripts would not be accessible because they'd be nicely wrapped up in a scoping function. You'd have to make them available somehow, perhaps through a single shared object available as a global variable (`var App = {};` and then they add themselves to `App`), or by having them raise an event on an existing global (`document.body`) that passes a reference to them to listeners.

Comment: the scripts loaded are all unwrapped. Via web inspector, I can see the loaded scripts are all viewable in the `XHRs` directory. Would they be accessible from there?

Comment: Ok it seems there's a problem with one of my included scripts as when I comment all but one out the done callback works fine. Thanks for your help.