# Download several js script asynchronously, but then execute them in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, ember.js

I'm building an application using Ember.js.  There's an administration portion of the website that requires the use of some various JavaScript libraries.

I'd like to download these libraries only when the administrative route of the site is visited.

I figured I could do something like in the following StackOverflow answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11803418/2014469

```
$.when(
    $.getScript( "/mypath/myscript1.js" ),
    $.getScript( "/mypath/myscript2.js" ),
    $.getScript( "/mypath/myscript3.js" ),
    $.Deferred(function( deferred ){
        $( deferred.resolve );
    })
).done(function(){

    //place your code here, the scripts are all loaded

});
```

But I'm nervous about the order of execution for those files.

Let's say that `myscript2.js` is dependent on some functions in `myscript1.js`.

Will `myscript1.js` be loaded ***(!)and executed(!)*** before `myscript2.js`?

If it isn't, how can I asynchronously download all of the files, but then execute them in order?  I thought about just chaining `.then()`:

```
$.getScript( "/mypath/myscript1.js" )
.then(function{$.getScript( "/mypath/myscript2.js" )})
.then(function{$.getScript( "/mypath/myscript3.js" )})
```

But that would wait until one has been downloaded and executed before it even starts downloading the next - I'd like to download all at the same time, but then execute them in order.

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: http://requirejs.org/

Comment: I've been looking at it - but I seriously only need this in one place on my site, and on the surface, it doesn't look like it's going to be necessary to include another library to load these others... The minified version *is* only 14kb though... Hmm...

Comment: What you are looking for is called promise chaining. I would privide a sample but I am currently on my cell.

Comment: Maybe not the most elegant option, but could you concat the admin only js libraries all into one js file, and just load that?

Comment: It was a thought that crossed my mind.  That just might be the route that I go.

Comment: Bundle them, easiest solution if you don't want to always include them, and don't want to use requirejs.  If you use getScript asynchronously it is going to execute them when it's fetched them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a javascript loader that manages dependencies between scripts.

If requirejs is too big for your needs and you don't plan to write one yourself, take a look at these smaller libraries:
http://microjs.com/#loader