# Load files and then call a call back function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my project, I am loading some `js` and `css` files by default in `index.html` file. But I need to load some other `js`/`css` files using javascript later (*dynamically*) and then after those dynamic files are loaded successfully, I need to call a callback function.

I checked [`jQuery.getScript()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/), which is calling callback function after each file is loaded but not all files are loaded.

I tried this:

```
function loadFiles(payload, callbackFunc) {
    var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var fileref = null;
    if (payload.js) {
        var js = payload.js;
        for (var i = 0; i < js.length; i++) {
            var file = this.getPath("files", js[i]);
            if (!file.loaded) {
                var fileref = document.createElement('script');
                fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
                fileref.setAttribute("src", file.path);
                fileref.onreadystatechange = callbackFunc;
                fileref.onload = callbackFunc;
                head.appendChild(fileref);
                file.loaded = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (payload.css) {
        var css = payload.css;
        for (var i = 0; i < css.length; i++) {
            var file = this.getPath("files", css[i]);
            if (!file.loaded) {
                var fileref = document.createElement('link');
                fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
                fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
                fileref.setAttribute("href", file.path);
                fileref.onreadystatechange = callbackFunc;
                fileref.onload = callbackFunc;
                head.appendChild(fileref);
                file.loaded = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please someone help me on how to solve this issue.

## Answer:

Somehow the below answers didn't work for me. I wasn't able to see the dynamically added scripts in developer tool of chrome. So, I ended up modifying my above code by referring @jfriend00's answer:

```
function loadFiles(list, fn){
    var counter = 0;
    var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var fileref = document.createElement('script');
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        fileref.setAttribute("src", list[i]);
        fileref.onload = function(){
            counter++;
            if(counter === list.length){
                fn();
            }
        }
        head.appendChild(fileref);
    }
    if(list.length === 0){
        fn();
    }
}
```

Comment: `$.getScript()` sounds like it is exactly what you require so I don't see why it wouldn't work. Can you please add the code you've tried to your question.

Comment: also any error in console ?

Comment: no errors, it is just that the same call back is being called for each loaded file.

Comment: i am unable to find `$.getScript` :/

Comment: @NullPoiиteя I didn't use it. I just checked the example where only one file is being loaded at a time but not an array (_which is my requirement_)

Comment: Do you want to call callback function only once when all are loaded?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Using that I can only load one file at a time.

Comment: Since you're loading multiple files, you can keep a counter, increment the counter when each file is loaded and only call the callback when the counter reaches the total indicating that all files have been loaded.

Comment: The first result in google for [jquery getscript multiple](https://www.google.com.au/?gws_rd=ssl#q=jquery+getscript+multiple) seems to provide the exact answer you seek: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803215/how-to-include-multiple-js-files-using-jquery-getscript-method

Comment: @jcubic yes... I think I am not clear in explanation.

Comment: @ChristianVaarga thanks that seems to work. will check in deep soon.

Comment: how Community♦ closed this question ? so 5 close votes no longer required to close question ?

Comment: @NullPoiиteя community asked me whether this post is dup of the other.. I said yes. and this got closed.

Comment: @NullPoiиteя - users with a certain number of privilege points in questions with a common tag to the one in question can close a question as a duplicate unilaterally (with one single vote).  If you think that is done in err, you can vote to reopen and/or flag for moderator attention.  Though, in this case it appears the action may have been taken by a moderator of some sort since the user Community doesn't look like a regular user.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for information , its all clear now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to use `$.getScript()` to load multiple files using a counter:

```
function getScripts(list, fn) {
    var cntr = list.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        $.getScript(list[i], function() {
            --cntr;
            if (cntr === 0) {
                fn();
            }
        });
    }
}

getScripts(["file1.js", "file2.js"], function() {
    // all scripts loaded here
});
```

Here's a way using promises:

```
function getScripts(list) {
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        promises.push($.getScript(list[i]));
    }
    return $.when.apply($, promises);
}


getScripts(["file1.js", "file2.js"]).then(function() {
    // all scripts loaded here
});
```

You can use these same concepts for your CSS files.

Answer (score 2):

To call callback function only once you need to do this check:

```
var count = 0;
fileref.onload = function() {
    if (payload.js.length + payload.css.length == ++count) {
        callbackFunc();
    }
};
```

Comment: Don't you have to do `count++` before the `if` statement?