# How can I know when Ajax calls are finished with getScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using jQuery `getScript` to load X amount of js files into my page. Each of those JS pages has an AJAX call in it that fetches data from the database.

I am using the `.done` method on `getScript` to see when all of the files have been loaded but I need to wait until all of the AJAX calls have been completed as well.

How can I go about waiting for the AJAX calls to finish in the included files via `getScript` before doing something?

```
$.getMultiScripts(moduleIncludes, 'includes/js/modules/').done(function() {
    // All of the JS files have been included but we need to wait until those files have finished their AJAX call.     
});

// Get array of JS scripts to load
$.getMultiScripts = function(arr, path) {

  var _arr = $.map(arr, function(scr) {
      return $.getScript((path || "") + scr);
  });

  _arr.push($.Deferred(function(deferred) {
      $(deferred.resolve);
  }));

  return $.when.apply($, _arr);
}
```

Comment: Make all the procedures write their finish state somewhere. Then you need to query that "somewhere" (the server, the localStorage, or whatever) in order to check if all the procedures have finished.

Comment: @threadp How would I go about waiting or checking on the status of something like this?

Comment: Install a `setTimeout` handler that both checks for completion and, if everything is complete (loaded), execute further code.

Comment: @threadp Thanks for the suggestion. I will keep it in mind but will continue to look for a more stable solution.

Comment: If you know the number of files you can use a counter.

Comment: What is purpose of `_arr.push($.Deferred(function(deferred) {
      $(deferred.resolve);
  }));`?

Comment: @guest271314 - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11803418/2628921

Comment: Are you using any other promise libraries other than jquery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.ajaxStop()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/)

> Whenever an Ajax request completes, jQuery checks whether there are
>   any other outstanding Ajax requests. If none remain, jQuery triggers
>   the `ajaxStop` event.

```
$(document).on("ajaxStop", function() {
  // do stuff when all `$.ajax()` call have complete
  $(document).off("ajaxStop")
});

$.getMultiScripts(moduleIncludes, 'includes/js/modules/').done(function() {
    // All of the JS files have been included but we need to wait until those files have finished their AJAX call.     
});
```

---

An alternative approach would be to use `$.when.apply()` twice. That is, push ajax calls into a second array

`"module1.js"`

```
data.push($.get("/path/to/module1-resource"))
```

```
var modules = ["module1.js", "module2.js", "module3.js"];
// declare global `data` array
data = [];

$.getMultiScripts = function(arr, path) {

  var _arr = $.map(arr, function(scr) {
      return $.getScript(scr)
  });

  return $.when.apply($, _arr.concat($.when()))
}

$.getMultiScripts(arr)
.then(function() {
  console.log("getScript calls", arguments)
  $.when.apply($, data).then(function() {
    console.log("ajax calls", arguments)
  })
});
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/si2EsUZOciOwU4nAPlS9?p=preview

Comment: well that's pretty damn cool - I think that will solve my need.