# working with defer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, deferred-loading

I have used defer for my project (to pass google page speed test)
[image]

but my lazy plugin is not working as expect and this is my jquery lazy function to worked all lazy images

[image]

but all image is not loading how can be possible ?

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" defer></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" defer></script>
<script src="js/plugin.js" defer></script>
<script src="js/main.js" defer onload="loadImages()"></script>
```

MY JS

```
function loadImages(){
  $(".lazy").lazy();
};
```

[click to see demo page - when page loaded scroll down please](http://firatabak.com/test/anasayfa.html)

Comment: Where are you loading lazy load? It needs to be loaded after jquery.

Comment: @sideroxylon it is in top of the main.js and I called it with onload when page load

Comment: Check your console to see if jquery has loaded before the onload event.

Comment: you demo page is missing "defer onload="loadImages()" for <script src="js/main.js"></script>

Comment: I checked the timing in the network tab of the console, and main.js finishes loading before jquery.min.js

Comment: @sideroxylon and what I have to do ? if I change order of js my html won't work ?

Comment: Start by trying not deferring jquery and see if your timing is OK

Comment: Looks to be working now.

Comment: I guess it works as expect but must work with defer and can be issue order of the js ?

Comment: no..I know it will work but the problem is defer..I gotta work with defer

Comment: Look at the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803215/how-to-include-multiple-js-files-using-jquery-getscript-method) - defer jquery, then run a function to load the dependencies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129879/discussion-between-recruit-man-and-sideroxylon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think with `defer`, the scripts are `loaded` in parallel but `executed` in order. So, its possible that `loadImages` is called before its dependent scripts are loaded and executed.

If the call to `loadImages` is inside `main.js` then it will be called after all other deferred scripts before it are loaded & executed, and lazy loading should work.

Again, browser implementations vary.

Comment: and you say I gotta remove onload on my html right?

Comment: yes. remove onload from your script tag. put the call to loadImages inside main.js. try it.