# jQuery getScript to load external script and call function that relies on script not working

Tags: jquery, getscript

I have the following code to load an external script, I can see in the console network tab the script gets loaded but  I get error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).pikaday is not a function
```

This is my script:

```
<input class="my-datepicker" id="from_date" type="text" placeholder="From" name="from_date" value="">

<script>

$(window).on('load', function() {

   $.when(
      $.getScript( "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pikaday/1.8.0/pikaday.min.js" ),
      $.Deferred(function( deferred ){
          $( deferred.resolve );
      })
   ).done(function(){

      $(".my-datepicker").pikaday({
         firstDay: 1
      });

  })

});

</script>
```

Comment: [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/): _"The callback is fired once the script has been loaded **but not necessarily executed**"_

Comment: And why `$.Deferred(function( deferred ){ $( deferred.resolve ); })`?

Comment: @Andreas so how do i fix this?

Comment: @Andreas see the following answer for details on why `$.Deffered` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803215/how-to-include-multiple-js-files-using-jquery-getscript-method

Comment: _"...because of the $.Deferred call which resolves in the DOM ready callback."_ - Your script is executed way after `DOMReady` ([window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)), hence that promise/deferred will be resolved immediately and is therefor useless.

Comment: @andreas very well but you haven't provided any alternative solution to fix the issue at hand.