# How do I add a delay to a script tag that includes params?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

I would like to add a delay for this code including the async and the data attributes.

```
<script async src="https://s.widgetwhats.com/wwwa.js" data-wwwa="1"></script>
```

I saw this solution on stackoverflow [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611714/delay-script-loading) but it doesn't include the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

*script* with *async* attribute means it will be executed as soon as it is downloaded, regardless of whether the rest of the page is loaded.

If you want a delay before loading the *script*, you can remove the *async* attribute and use the [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) function to delay the execution like the following way:

```
<script>
  setTimeout(function() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "https://s.widgetwhats.com/wwwa.js";
    script.setAttribute('data-wwwa', '1');
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, 2000); //delay in milliseconds (2 seconds)
</script>
```

Comment: Appreciate the clear explanation along with the code example. Bless you 